# Image tint color change in iOS XCode 11.4

Tags: ios, swift, tintcolor, xcode11.4

I a trying to change image tint color in XCode 11.4 but it is not working. It was working in previous versions, I could change tint color from story board. Now changing tint color from story board does not reflect.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Change image render as and then it works

Comment: Happy coding...